# How to get Primary key from ManagedObjects retrieved from Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, primary-key

I've 'ChildDetails' entity and have kids details. I'd like to retrieve the Primary key for the row for each kid.

How can i retrieve that primary key that is auto generated by Core Data.?

I've attached Screenshot of CHILDDETAILS Table. I want to get Z_PK Value from the ChildDetails. How can i do that.?

[image: Screenshot of Table]